# Why does the amplitude decrease due to friction in forced vibrations?

Tags: acoustics, friction, frequency, oscillators

Basically, in forced vibrations the frequency of the external force is acquired by the body when both the natural frequency and external frequency is different (won't go into that too because I'll get to learn it in higher-grade classes), but my question is why does the amplitude decrease due to dampening forces? If I'm periodically applying a force, shouldn't that overcome any sort of frictional force?

Also, is this a case of destructive interference? Cause in one place, it's written that it acquires the external frequency, and in another place, it says the amplitude decreases if they are different and the sound dies out because of resistive forces.

Comment: Please. Read your question, to realize if it could be a way to WRITE. You're not talking to someone. Add some punctuation marks, remove "ok fine", add apostrophe where needed,...

Answer (score 0):

Having a forcing term leads to the ability to continually pump energy into a system.  However, if there is friction then any time there is motion energy is being pulled out of the system.  The more friction there is, the more energy that gets pulled out.  If you are looking at a place very close to the energy source then there is comparitively little friction, and the amplitude can be large.  However, farther from the source the sound has had to propagate farther and interacted with more friction, and so more of the energy is lost and the amplitude drops.  Thus, farther from the source the amplitude drops due to the friction.

A full mathematical description of this phenomenon is beyond the scope of this website, but it may be helpful to see what the solution to the pressure is for sound in a tube.  If there is a loudspeaker at $x=0$ in a tube that extends to positive $x$, and the loudspeaker induces a pressure such that the pressure $p$ satisfies
$$p(0,t) = A\cos(2\pi f t),$$
where $A$ is the amplitude, $f$ is the frequency, and $t$ is the time, then we may write the pressure everywhere as
$$p(x,t)=Ae^{-\alpha x}\cos(2\pi f [t - x/c]),$$
where $\alpha$ is called the absorption coefficient, and is related to strength of the friction and the frequency of the signal.  Also, $c$ here is the sound speed.  Notice that the amplitude of the wave decreases exponentially with distance from the source.  More complicated scenarios are, naturally, more complicated, but this basic principle remains true.